# Checkout page error - Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento muti store. I am using same theme for all of my store. All my store working properly except one, the problem is that my onepage checkout not working.

When I click on procceed to checkout the page redirects to checkout page, but it is not working.

As default checkout method is open, but not in my site. It was working before one day. Suddenly stopped working.

When I checked the errors in chrome debug mode, there showed an error,

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Accordion is not defined."

Is this error happen because of this JavaScript error? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you jQuery library or UI library is not loading properly - verify that the

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

are in the right order - jquery first then the ui, and whether those files are accessible from this particular website/storeview

Comment: But I have other magento store which have same file structure and code. Those are working. Why this site only?

Comment: I have checked. I have a jquery-1.6.2.min.js and a jquery-ui.min.js file.

Comment: Firstly verify whether those libs are really not available on this particular storeview - maybe its wrong direction to look - but that would be my first check. Try also just use jQuery in the chrome console - to verify whether it's loaded, U could also try init the accordion by hand using the console and verify whether this fixes the issue

Comment: buy init the accordion i mean trying sth like this `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();` from the chrome console - this way you will be able to verify whether the lib is available, try also 'jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion();`

Comment: actually my domain.com/js/varien/accordion.js file showing 522 connection time out error, what can I do?

Comment: other storeviews are on the same domain? This file on other storeviews/domains is accessiable? If yes then it is a server issue.

Comment: other stores are on the same domain? If yes then is this file accessible from different domain? If yes then I'd say it is an issue in the server configuration and that is why the file cannot by loaded

Comment: Thanks bro. This was the problem from the server people and they rectified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update following files from fresh magento installed. this files responsible for checkout step.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem from the server people and they rectified it. Thanks guys.